# New Snow Leopard ... "Select All" won't Trash

Tags: macos

Just ran Snow Leopard on my 10.4 Tiger iMac6.1 desktop.  All has gone swimmingly.  But now ... the way I work, I have several icons, photos, on desktop when I'm finished and I Trash them.

Clicking Edit, "Select All" highlights all, and when I drag all into Trash, it doesn't Trash.  I can individually select an icon, click and drag, into Trash.
But "Select All" doesn't work.

Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Likely there's an item in your 'select all' that cannot be trashed; a .dmg in use or a mounted disk (your hard drive, a CD-ROM, a flash drive), for example.
That'll prevent *anything* in your selection from going into trash.

Answer (score 0):

Hold Command when you select the trash empty button

Comment: He doesn't seem to be able to even move the files to the trash. Forced emptying won't help here.

Comment: Right ... all highlight and move as a group but won't stay dropped into trash.  Ab